# WPF visualtreehelper.getchildrencount returns 0 on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visualtreehelper

I am using datagrid with 32 rows and when I try to use this GetCell(28,2) its fail, and also on row 28 - 32 there is the same problem.

this one:  `visualtreehelper.getchildrencount` return 0 when its above row 28.

I find out that if i roll down to those hidden rows on the datagrid I can get those rows with  GetCell() and its work fine.

how i can do that without roll down?

```
    public DataGridCell GetCell(int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(row);

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column); 
            if (cell == null)
            {
                datagrid_arinc_const.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, datagrid_arinc_const.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public DataGridRow GetRow(int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)datagrid_arinc_const.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            datagrid_arinc_const.UpdateLayout();
            datagrid_arinc_const.ScrollIntoView(datagrid_arinc_const.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)datagrid_arinc_const.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do because it's likely you shouldn't be trying this approach in the first place.

Comment: By default virtualization is On for Datagrid which means only visible containers are generated. In case you want to get dataGridRow or cell which is not visible you have to scroll down to that row manually from code behind so that its container gets generated OR you have to disable UI virtualization off on dataGrid (in case don't want to scroll down).

Comment: @RohitVats thank you! I scroll down manually from code and its work well.

Comment: Great I'll convert is an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **UI virtualization is On for Datagrid** which means *only visible containers are generated*.

In case you want to get dataGridRow or cell which is not visible you have to **scroll down to that row manually from code behind so that its container gets generated**.
Refer this article [here](http://techiethings.blogspot.in/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html) to manually scroll dataGridRow into view.

OR

**Disable UI virtualization Off on dataGrid** (in case don't want to scroll down) by setting [VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualising](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false on your datagrid.

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"/>
```

Comment: After some tries on me code, it's seem that the scroll down is not working so well, but disable the UI virtualization Off on dataGrid work nice.